# Can i get some field like "Panel" from the Frame in java AWT?

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, field, panel

I'm new to Java and now am learning building GUI using AWT (not Swing!)

So, I have created:

1. A `Frame` (let it call f).
2. A class, which creates me a `CheckBox` in the `Panel` in constructor:

   ```
   public class CheckBoxing extends Component{
       public CheckBoxing( Panel p) { 
           ...
           }
   }
   ```

Is there a field in `Frame` which I can use to initialize an exemplar of `CheckBoxing`? I know, I can simply rewrite `CheckBoxing` to accept `Frame` instead of `Panel`, or use `JFrame`, but this will ruin the idea I'm trying to implement.

Comment: 1- If you're new to Java, then use the Swing API or JavaFX, you'll get better support. 2- `Frame` is an ancestor of `Container` and `Component`, so you'd have more like using those, which are a common ancestor to `Panel`

Comment: 1) *"or use `JFrame`,"*  Wait ..what?  A `Frame` can do pretty much whatever a `JFrame` can do, so that makes me aware of the fact that I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. 2) And to echo @MadProgrammer but expand: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.  (I can't speak for Java FX.)